# POST request and nginx

Tags: sockets, nginx, http-post, keep-alive

I'm trying to send a lot of post-requests to the `localhost:80` (nginx-server).

The headers I'm sending are:

```
POST /LINK HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: User agent
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 16

DATA 16 BYTES
```

The pseudocode is:

```
TCPSocket sock('localhost', 80);
for(;;) {
   sock.sendPost();
}
sock.close();
```

But server returns **first** time:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2012 14:54:26 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 92
Connection: close

ANSWER 92 BYTES
```

So server doesn't work with all another post-request from cycle.

Why does not `Connection: Keep-Alive` work and server returns `Connection: close`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `keepalive_timeout` and `keepalive_requests` to [proper values](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#keepalive_requests).

Comment: They are proper. The problem is that server doesn't care about my header and anyways makes closed connection.